# Istio\Envoy: how to turn off headers normalization

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

Istio perform some normalization on duplicate HTTP headers: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/normalization/#2-duplicate-headers

```
Istio will merge duplicate headers to a single header by concatenating all values using comma as a separator.
This is enabled by default
```

If enabled by default - looks like should be a way to disable it. I tried to find in Istio docs - no luck, does anybody know how to disable it via Istio EnvoyFilter patch?

Thank you

In envoy it is looks like part of "HeaderMutationRules structure": https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/common/mutation_rules/v3/mutation_rules.proto.